# Error make: *** [.obj/channel.o] Error 1

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

Can anybody help me?
when i built project qsopcast-0.3.4

```
thequang@thequang-Inspiron-N4030:~/qsopcast-0.3.4/src$ qmake
thequang@thequang-Inspiron-N4030:~/qsopcast-0.3.4/src$ make
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -O2 -D_REENTRANT  -DALSA -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I/usr/share/qt3/mkspecs/default -I. -I. -I/usr/share/qt3/include -I.moc/ -o .obj/channel.o channel.cpp
In file included from channel.cpp:21:0:
header.h:4:26: fatal error: qapplication.h: No such file or directory
 #include <qapplication.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.obj/channel.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to build this on? according to the qsopcast-0.3.4 README file, it requires qt3: AFAIK the last version to provide a Qt3 development environment from the standard repositories was 12.04 (Precise).

Comment: Can you help me! How to install lib-qt3? i use ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Install libqt4-dev or qtbase5-dev

Comment: I installed! But nothing!

Comment: Download the source code and start a make and you will see, that your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it does. It was incorrect though.